Arduino UNO R4 WiFi, Gravity I2C 4-20mA DAC, Mass Flow Controller
I'm trying make a open source system to operate a mass-flow-controller (MFC) over the web. The MFC is operated with a linear current 4-20mA, with 4mA-ValveClosed and 20mA-ValveOpen. I'm using an arduino uno r4 wifi board and an Gravity IC2 4-20mA DAC breakoutboard purchased from dfrobot (https://www.dfrobot.com/product-2625.html). I want my arduino to standby on an dedicated IP address and listen for incoming clients and accordingly control the MFC. For example, when a client sents 10.0.0.35/15, the arduino sets the Gravity I2C DAC to a setpont of 15mA which eventually cotrolles the MFC. I've written the code bellow, but the problem is that the arduino-DAC doesn't hold the setpoint and keeps reseting when the connection is closed!
    #include "DFRobot_GP8302.h"
    DFRobot_GP8302 module;
    #include <WiFi.h>
    #include <WiFiClient.h>
    #include <WiFiServer.h>
    #include "RTC.h"

    const char* ssid     = "abc123";
    const char* password = "abc";
    volatile int set;
    const int mfc_flow_pin = A2;
    WiFiServer server(80); // Create a webserver on port 80

    int mfc_flow_pin_value = 0;

    void setup(){
      Serial.begin(115200);
      RTC.begin();
      RTCTime startTime(30, Month::JUNE, 2023, 13, 37, 00, DayOfWeek::WEDNESDAY, SaveLight::SAVING_TIME_ACTIVE);
      RTC.setTime(startTime);
      while(!Serial){

      }
      Serial.print("I2C to 0-25 mA analog current moudle initialization ... ");
      uint8_t status = module.begin(); // use the pin used by the I2C Wire object of the MCU hardware by default

      if(status != 0){
        Serial.print("failed. Error code: ");
        Serial.println(status);
        Serial.println("Error Code: ");
        Serial.println("\t1: _scl or _sda pin is invaild.");
        Serial.println("\t2: Device not found, please check if the device is connected.");
        while(1) yield();
      }
      Serial.println("done!");
      uint16_t dac = module.output(set); //control the converter module to output a current of 10mA and return the corresponding DAC value
      Serial.print("DAC value: 0x"); 
      Serial.println(dac, HEX);
      module.store(); 
      Serial.println("Save current configuration."); //the above current config will be saved and will not be lost after power off
      // Attempt to connect to WiFi
      Serial.print("Connecting to ");
      Serial.println(ssid); 
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password); 
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
      {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }
      // Connected to WiFi
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
      Serial.println("IP address: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
      // Start the server
      server.begin();
    }

    void setOutput(uint16_t value) {
      //Serial.print("I2C to 0-25 mA analog current moudle initialization ... ");
      uint8_t status = module.begin();
      if(status != 0){
        //Serial.print("failed. Error code: ");
        //Serial.println(status);
        //Serial.println("Error Code: ");
        //Serial.println("\t1: _scl or _sda pin is invaild.");
        //Serial.println("\t2: Device not found, please check if the device is connected.");
        while(1) yield();
      }
      //Serial.println("done!");

      uint16_t dac = module.output(value);
      //Serial.print("DAC value: 0x"); 
      //Serial.println(dac, HEX);
      module.store(); 
      //Serial.println("Save current configuration.");
      set = value;
      delay(100);
    }

    void loop(){
      RTCTime currentTime;
      RTC.getTime(currentTime);
      mfc_flow_pin_value = map(analogRead(mfc_flow_pin), 0, 1023, 4, 20);

      WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients
      if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
        String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
        while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
          if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
            char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
            if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character

              // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
              // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
              if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
                // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
                // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
                client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                client.println("Content-type:text/html");
                client.println();
                
                // the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
                int ts = currentTime.getUnixTime();
                client.print("Unix Time: ");
                client.println(ts);
                client.print("Flow [4-20mA] = ");
                client.println(mfc_flow_pin_value);
                client.print("Setpoint [4-20mA] = ");
                client.println(set);

                // The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
                client.println();
                // break out of the while loop:
                break;
              } else {    // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
                currentLine = "";
              }
            } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
              currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
              // Check if the current line starts with "GET /"
              if (currentLine.startsWith("GET /")) {
                // Extract the integer from the request
                int value = currentLine.substring(5).toInt();
                // Call setOutput with the extracted value
                if (value > 20) {
                  value = 20;
                }
                if (value < 4) {
                  value = 4;
                }
                setOutput(value);
                // the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
                int ts = currentTime.getUnixTime();
                client.print("THIS IS ---> Unix Time: ");
                client.println(ts);
                mfc_flow_pin_value = map(analogRead(mfc_flow_pin), 0, 1023, 4, 20);
                delay(100);
                client.print("Flow [4-20mA] = ");
                client.println(mfc_flow_pin_value);
                client.print("Setpoint [4-20mA] = ");
                client.println(set);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        // close the connection:
        client.stop();
      }
      setOutput(set);
    }

I've tryed to call the setOutput(set) helper function in different positions but with no avail.

Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.
